# Using the cache count for acts_as_votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord

I have a view that is iterating through a series of posts, and is running a count on the votes for each. I know how to do eager loading generally and how to use cache counters generally. But I can't figure out how to use the cache counter that comes with acts_as_votable (or I'm doing something else wrong.)

View:

```
        <span class="votes">
        <% if current_user.voted_for? link %>
            <%= link_to like_link_path(link), class: "likes active", id: "link-#{link.id}", remote: true, method: :put do %>
            <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <%= link.cached_votes_total.to_s %>
            <% end %>
        <% else %>
            <%= link_to like_link_path(link), class: "likes", id: "link-#{link.id}", remote: true, method: :put do %>
            <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> <%= link.cached_votes_total.to_s %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
        </span>
```

Terminal:

```
Link Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "links".* FROM "links"  ORDER BY "links"."score" DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (1)
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
(0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."voter_id" = $1 AND "votes"."voter_type" = $2 AND "votes"."votable_id" = $3 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $4 AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["voter_id", 1], ["voter_type", "User"], ["votable_id", 1], ["votable_type", "Link"]]
(0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."voter_id" = $1 AND "votes"."voter_type" = $2 AND "votes"."votable_id" = $3 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $4 AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["voter_id", 1], ["voter_type", "User"], ["votable_id", 2], ["votable_type", "Link"]]
Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (24.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 60ms (Views: 56.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looked nothing abnormal to me. The `voted_for?` method is alias of `voted_on?`. Keep on reading the code you will find this method calls a `votes.size > 0`, which will trigger following queries to database. (I guess you have 2 links on your page, right?) So it has nothing to do with the cached counts fields.

```
(0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."voter_id" = $1 AND "votes"."voter_type" = $2 AND "votes"."votable_id" = $3 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $4 AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["voter_id", 1], ["voter_type", "User"], ["votable_id", 1], ["votable_type", "Link"]]
(0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."voter_id" = $1 AND "votes"."voter_type" = $2 AND "votes"."votable_id" = $3 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $4 AND "votes"."vote_scope" IS NULL  [["voter_id", 1], ["voter_type", "User"], ["votable_id", 2], ["votable_type", "Link"]]
```

P.S. The code is here: [github: voter.rb](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable/blob/9ded371ec0720d07fa7a169109da05c835a2cb51/lib/acts_as_votable/voter.rb).

Comment: Yeah, to avoid every link calling a query I want to know which model should I `includes`. This question is about eager loading, right? That's why I create a bounty for this question.

Answer (score 2):

May be that is not the best way, but it could help to preload user's votes for links in single database hit:

1. Somewhere in backend (e.g. User model) you may define method like

   ```
   # votable - records, which were voted by user, links in the case
   def preloaded_votes(votable)
     @preloaded_votes ||= Vote.where(voter: self, votable: votable).group(:votable_id).count
   end
   ```

   this method will return hash like `{votable_id1 => count1, votable_id2 => count2 }`, where `votable_idN` means id of an element from `votable` argument for the method.
2. Change current call `current_user.voted_for? link` to preloaded counts `current_user.preloaded_votes.key?(link.id)`

This solution adds one more database hit, but allow to avoid `N+1` queries. Also, additional SQL does not contain any tables joins. One possible way to improve here - add special index for this kind of queries.